# Add tag <hour> that will contain time hh:mm from date

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<output>
<orders>
<order>
<id>1</id>
<number>10002</number>
<type>Loading</type>
<date>2013-01-01T02:30:00</date>
</order>
<order>
<id>2</id>
<number>10003</number>
<type>Loading</type>
<date>2013-01-01T010:30:00</date>
</order>
<order>
<id>3</id>
<number>10004</number>
<type>Loaded</type>
<date>2013-01-01T12:30:00</date>
</order>
</orders>
<quantities>
<quantity>
<id_order>1</id_order>
<unit>KG</unit>
<value>1000</value>
</quantity>
<quantity>
<id_order>1</id_order>
<unit>PAL</unit>
<value>3</value>
</quantity>
<quantity>
<id_order>1</id_order>
<unit>M3</unit>
<value>1.5</value>
</quantity>
<quantity>
<id_order>2</id_order>
<unit>KG</unit>
<value>2000</value>
</quantity>
<quantity>
<id_order>2</id_order>
<unit>PAL</unit>
<value>4</value>
</quantity>
<quantity>
<id_order>3</id_order>
<unit>KG</unit>
<value>5000</value> 
</quantity>
</quantities>
</output>
```

I need to extract time from date of every order and put it in a new tag  after the date.
I've only managed to create the tag

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="date">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <hour>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(output/orders/order/date,12,5)"/> 
       </hour>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't work, I cant' show the time in the new tag.

Can someone help me please?

BR

Answer (score 1):

Current context element is `<date>` already, so you can simply use `.` instead of `output/orders/order/date` here :

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(.,12,5)"/>
```